# Does the principle of least action assume the kinetic energy law as an axiom?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I should probably wait till I finish the complete derivation before asking this. but maybe it will help me to know ahead of time. I like to always know what the axiom's are before I start a topic and the book (" The Physical World " by Nicholas Mee) starts with kinetic energy in it's derivation of the principle of least action.

Simply I am seeing the kinetic energy formula as a starting point to compute the least action. From what I can recall kinetic energy is derived from calculus or algebra starting with the work energy theorem.

So I would hope the least action theorem (when I finish) will not claim it's end result can be used to derive what has already been assumed to be axiomatic, namely the work energy theorem? (a statement in the form of a question because I do not know)

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to include a definition of the 'kinetic energy law' to ensure everybody is using the same definition. Is it the same as the 'work energy theorem'? Or the 'kinetic energy formula'?

Comment: In Landau's book, I believe, the definition of kinetic energy is rationalized as the simplest scalar object you can construct from velocity (i.e. some constant multiplied by $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$).

Comment: I got it now.....the wikihow to article is really crappy....they used a period to signify multiplication and I though it was dot product and that is because in the same derivation they do not use a period for multiplication by the default which is nothing....so I found a derivation.   but is assumes f =ma so to answer my own question it must be an axiom otherwise it is circular reasoning

Comment: probably_someone ...can you tell me why the 1/2 is in front of the mv  ^2 ..supposedly  this is your postulate ...the 1/2 comes out if you use F=ma for a starting point to first derive the kinetic energy...if you don't use f=ma  and your not supposed to ...remember the least action is the superior way of deriving Newton's motion laws ... you have to start with the kinetic energy formula stand alone ...so where does that pesky 1/2 come from ?